# Watson Assistant and Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I made a chatbot using Assistant, and in the console it works perfectly. However when I followed the tutorial to add Watson to an iOS app, it stopped working in the app only. For example in my dialog tree I am only able to access the first child and get the response from there.

However it asks a question, and then when I respond to that question, it just **returns empty quotes**. I am very confused because the online console still works perfectly, but the app is very broken.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out! I was not passing the correct input context, so it was like the conversation was starting anew every single time.